# Exception of null object reference when click on Text area in popup in Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import comps.sampleTextArea;

        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;



        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var pop:sampleTextArea = new sampleTextArea();
            PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, sampleTextArea, false);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(pop);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="open popup"/>
```

and here is code of popup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            ta.text = '';
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top" />
</s:layout>
<s:TextArea id="ta" width="100%" height="90%">

</s:TextArea>
<s:Button label="Submit" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
```

when i click on text area following error through by the application.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at spark.components::Scroller/focusInHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Scroller.as:2139]
at flash.display::Stage/set focus()
at flashx.textLayout.container::ContainerController/http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/internal/2008::setFocus()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\container\ContainerController.as:2265]
at flashx.textLayout.container::ContainerController/mouseDownHandler()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\container\ContainerController.as:2067]
at flashx.textLayout.container::TextContainerManager/mouseDownHandler()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\container\TextContainerManager.as:1939]
at spark.components.supportClasses::RichEditableTextContainerManager/mouseDownHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\RichEditableTextContainerManager.as:666]
at flashx.textLayout.container::ContainerController/http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/internal/2008::requiredMouseDownHandler()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\container\ContainerController.as:2088]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2918]
```

How i handle this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing many experiments/ways i conclude that problem is due to the popup component parent container.

I use Group/VGroup/HGroup of spark then this issue remains but if i change the parent container with spark Panel/SkinnableContainer then issue solved.

Try yourself and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

try, because `this` refer to stage no the clicked element:

```
PopUpManager.removePopUp(event.target);
```

Comment: but i want to add something in textarea and then remove popup.

Comment: @mgraph the problem is in clicking the text not the close button. As the error shows, the problem comes from the setFocus() method. And btw.. the PopUpManager.removePopUp(this); looks ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to popup a focusable component inside a
non-IFocusManagerContainer. If your Group container implements IFocusManagerContainer class, you may use PopUpManager.

```
<s:Group implements="mx.managers.IFocusManagerContainer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and the root cause was that PopUpManager/PopUpAnchor would not properly set the focusManager if the component being popped up does not implement the `IFocusManagerContainer` interface.  After implementing such interface, the problem goes away.

You may read this [blog post](http://eastmond.org/blog/?tag=popupmanager) that inspired the solution.